# Filtering dynamically generated search results in php

Tags: php, html, arrays, search

**Background to project**

I will start off by saying I am not the best at php and am a beginner by all accounts, but I have tried to create a php based search for my university project.

It is a smoothie recipe website, in the first instance a user will search by typing in a keyword, this will generate search results. This part I have got down fine. When it comes to filtering the results however, I am really struggling. The user should be able to filter by the fruits/vegetables/type of smoothie as well as the keyword itself. For example:

Keyword = apple Filters = mango(fruit filter), spinach(veg filter) detox (type filter)

However, what currently happens is, I will get every instance of apple, mango, spinach and detox smoothies. As well as this, if a smoothie contains both apple and mango for example it will generate that smoothie twice. I am aware I need to include array_unique() in here somewhere, but I really don't know where.

**PHP**

Here is my php so far:`

```
                    $dbhost = '*';
                    $dbuser = '*';
                    $dbpass = '*';
                    $dbname = '*';

                    $k = $_GET['k'];
                    $terms = explode(" ", $k);

                    //START THE QUERY HERE
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM search";

                    //FROM THE VIEW FIND OUT IF THE USER HAS CLICKED ON ANY FRUITS. 
                        //IF SO THEN JOIN THE SEARCH_METADATA TABLE TO THE QUERY SO YOU CAN FIND ALL THE POSSIBLE FRUITS
                    if (!empty($_GET['fl-Fruit'])) {
                        $query .= ' INNER JOIN search_metadata ON search_id = search.id';
                    }

                    //START THE WHERE CLAUSE HERE
                    $query .= ' WHERE ';

                    //FIRST LOOK FOR THE SEARCH TERM THE USER ENTERED
                    foreach ($terms as $each){
                        $i++;
                        if ($i == 1)

                            $query .= " keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
                        else 
                            $query .= " OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";

                    }

                    //ONCE THE SEARCH TERM HAS BEEN FOUND
                    //TODO ==== RUN CHECKS FOR VEG AND TYPE OPTIONS
                    if (isset($_GET['fl-Fruit'])) {

                        //SET ALL THE GET VARIABLES TO NEW VARIABLES JUST FOR MAKING IT EASIER TO READ
                        $fruits = $_GET['fl-Fruit'];


                        //FOREACH FRUITS SELECTED FROM THE FACET SEARCH
                            //RUN THROUGH EACH ONE IN THE WHERE CLAUSE.
                        foreach ($fruits as $fruit) {
                            $query .= " XOR value = '$fruit' ";
                        }

                    }
                    if (isset($_GET['fl-veg'])) {

                        //SET ALL THE GET VARIABLES TO NEW VARIABLES JUST FOR MAKING IT EASIER TO READ
                        $vegetables = $_GET['fl-veg'];


                        //FOREACH FRUITS SELECTED FROM THE FACET SEARCH
                            //RUN THROUGH EACH ONE IN THE WHERE CLAUSE.
                        foreach ($vegetables as $veg) {
                            $query .= " XOR value = '$veg' ";
                        }
                    }
                    if (isset($_GET['fl-s-type'])) {

                        //SET ALL THE GET VARIABLES TO NEW VARIABLES JUST FOR MAKING IT EASIER TO READ
                        $types = $_GET['fl-s-type'];


                        //FOREACH FRUITS SELECTED FROM THE FACET SEARCH
                            //RUN THROUGH EACH ONE IN THE WHERE CLAUSE.
                        foreach ($types as $type) {
                            $query .= " XOR value = '$type' ";
                        }
                    }

                    var_dump($query);


                    echo '<h1>' ."Your search results for $k". '</h1>';
                    //CONNECT TO DATABASE

                    mysql_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass");
                    mysql_select_db("$dbname");

                    $query = mysql_query($query);
                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

                    if ($numrows > 0) {

                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                            $id = $row ['id'];
                            $title = $row ['title'];
                            $description = $row ['description'];
                            $keywords = $row ['keywords'];
                            $link = $row ['link'];

                            echo "<div class='result'><img src='images/$id.jpg'><div class='result-text'><h2><a href='$link'>$title</a></h2>
                            <p>$description</p></div></div>";
                        }
                    }

                    else 
                        echo "No results for <b>$k</b>";

                    ?>`
```

**HTML Form**

```
<form class='form-wrapper' action='./search.php' method='get'>   
                    <input id='search' type='text' name='k' value='<?php echo $_GET['k']; ?>' />
                    <input type='submit' id="submit" value='search'>

                <div class="menu">
                    <strong><p class="menu-toggle"> Filter your search </p></strong>
                </div>
                <section class="filters">
                    <h2>Filter smoothies by Fruit:</h2>

                        <p>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-Fruit[]" value="apple" id="apple"> 
                            <label for="apple">Apple</label>
                        </p>
                        ...
                        <p>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-Fruit[]" value="strawberries" id="strawberries"> 
                            <label for="strawberries">Strawberries</label>
                        </p>                     



                    <h2>Filter smoothies by veg:</h2>
                        <p>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-veg[]" value="beetroot" id="beetroot">
                            <label for="beetroot">Beetroot</label>
                        </p>
                        ...
                        <p>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-veg[]" value="spinach" id="spinach"> 
                            <label for="spinach">Spinach</label><br>
                        </p>                  


                   <h2>Filter by smoothie type:</h2>

                        <p>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-s-type[]" value="detox" id="detox">
                            <label for="detox">Supet Detox</label>
                        </p>
                        ...
                        <p>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="fl-s-type[]" value="muscle" id="muscle">
                            <label for="muscle">Muscle Building</label>     
                        </p>  
                        </form>
```

**Tables**

I currently have two tables "search" and "search_metadata". The "search" table contains the keywords for the keyword search and the "search_metadata" table contains the properties for the filters and has the following columns "search_id" (foreign key), "type" (fruit, veg, type), "value" (apple, carrot, detox).

Just to reiterate what I am asking:

1. How do I incorporate Array_unique() to stop duplicate results appearing
2. How I make it so that if a user searches for "apple" then selects "mango" and "passionfruit" filters, that only smoothies with those 3 ingredients in will show (not showing smoothies with one of those ingredients in)

I hope there is enough information/not too much information, if I can improve this question please let me know, as this is the first time of me posting on here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would handle the searching logic in the SQL query itself instead of getting all of the 'Search' rows and filtering them in PHP. An example query for if the user searched for "apple", and selected the "mango" and "passionfruit" filters would be:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Search AS s JOIN Search_Metadata AS sm USING( search_id )
WHERE
    search_id = "apple" AND
    sm.value IN
    (
        "mango", "passionFruit"
    );
```

As a note, is MySQL style syntax.

There are a couple of ways to build a query like this. One is to simply use string manipulation in php. Another is to use a "query-builder" library, like [FluentPDO](http://fluentpdo.com/documentation.html)

I have a feeling your database design needs to be rethought.